# Error running bash script in supervisor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, supervisord

I have a bash script that makes some work supervising network stuff, it works great when I run it manually, but when I put it in supervisor the ifs and the whiles does not work, just stops before any of those programming sentences, echos, running cat, more and other things work just fine, but in the minute I put an if nothing else work from there on.
Please give me some tips, I really need to run this script from supervisor.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a script that has this problem and any and all errors that show up (make sure you are catching standard error from the script running, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Etan Reisner, I have already fix the problem, I will put it here so if anyone else have the same problem see why.
The problem was so simple (as usual) I was reading the content of text files /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier and /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate to detect when the network cable was plugged and unplugged and I was doing it with `more` that (I don't know why, because if I ran the script manually worked great) when was executed in supervisor stopped the execution there after the first `more`, I just changed to `cat` and that was it.
Haft a day spent to solve that.
Hope if someone gets into this kind of trouble find this answer and that way can solve the problem fast.
Regards